# Find Remaining day and time using jodatime

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I want to compare(finding remaining days and time between two days) using joda time.
I am taking two DateTime object like this(one is starting and another is ending)

```
DateTime endDate  = new DateTime(2011,12,25,0,0,0,0);   
DateTime strtDate = new DateTime();
```

Now i am interested to find remaining date and time like this
`days:49 Hrs:5 Min:52 Sec:45`(Not considering Year and month here..)

Now I go ahead with period class like this

```
Period period = new Period();

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendSeconds()
    .appendMinutes()
    .appendHours()
    .appendDays()
    .appendMonths()
    .appendYears()
    .printZeroNever()
    .toFormatter();
```

Now in result what i get year,month,Day,etc...
in this case i will get days between `1-30`(not 31,45,49...(which I want)) always.

So how can i get this thing(is there any method that I am missing) or I need to handle this programmatically, as I read that joda time is very flexible so I am very sure that there will be any method like this.

If you are familiar then kindly share your knowledge.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Defines all standard fields from days downwards with **[PeriodType.dayTime()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html#dayTime%28%29)**.

**For example** :

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.now(); // now() : since Joda Time 2.0
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 25, 0, 0);

Period period = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.dayTime());

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendDays().appendSuffix(" day ", " days ")
        .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour ", " hours ")
        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minute ", " minutes ")
        .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" second ", " seconds ")
        .toFormatter();

System.out.println(formatter.print(period));
```

**Sample output**

Period between `startDate` and `endDate` is

> 47 days 12 hours 46 minutes 47 seconds

---

**Or**

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPrefix("Day:", " Days:").appendDays()
        .appendPrefix(" Hour:", " Hours:").appendHours()
        .appendPrefix(" Minute:", " Minutes:").appendMinutes()
        .appendPrefix(" Second:", " Seconds:").appendSeconds()
        .toFormatter();
```

**with output**

> Days:47 Hours:12 Minutes:46 Seconds:47

Comment: Hey Ischin thank you,its working great,could not find that PeiodType is key for that.

Comment: Great man! this solved my 2 weeks searched problem! Thanks @Ischin

Comment: Thanks, works flawlessly! I was not using the PeriodType.dayTime () parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output in prettier format then you can use this snippet too

```
val startDate = DateTime.now()
val endDate = DateTime(endTime)
val period = Period(startDate, endDate)

val periodFormatter = PeriodFormatterBuilder().apply {
    when {
        period.days > 0 -> appendDays().appendSuffix(" day", " days")
        period.hours > 0 -> appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour", " hours")
        period.minutes > 0 -> appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minute", " minutes")
    }
}.toFormatter()

periodFormatter.print(period)
```