# CountDownTimer Format Milliseconds

Tags: java, time, timer, format

K So i am making a timer with CountDownTimer. it is my first app i am doing and i am already running into a problem. First my timer is skipping the number 14? no clue why. and second, I dont know how to set the proper format. "mm:ss" My biggest issue is setting format. I need to have it so when i get to 8 seconds left it read 00:08 etc. and when i have minute 15 left it read 1:15, and not 00:75 or 1:75. Its been a long day trying to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

```
private void walk() {
                new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        lapCounter++;
                        lapNumber.setText("Lap Number: " + lapCounter);
                        run();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        text.setText("Time left:" + millisUntilFinished/1000);

                    }


                }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026136/find-remaining-day-and-time-using-jodatime) for details

Comment: I am not looking for another way to use a timer. Just a way to format. I appreciate the advice on Joda-time. I will look into it.